# Health check failing to fetch the version number in github actions runners

Tags: linux, curl, wget, health-check, github-actions-runners

I have a workflow file which has 3 similar jobs which are running health check on a website but all of them are behaving differently and the behavior seems to be fully random and can't seem to find a valid reason. I have tried all possible combinations of wget and curl commands.

Here's a snapshot of the workflow jobs:

[image: this is the overview of the workflow]

and here's the **test.sh** file

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$status" != "0" ]; do
    sleep 5
    # curl <WEBSITE GOES HERE>
    wget -S --spider <WEBSITE GOES HERE> 2>&1 | grep HTTP/
    # curl -v --silent <WEBSITE GOES HERE> 2>&1 | grep -Po $1
    wget <WEBSITE GOES HERE> -q -O - | grep -Po $1
    status=$(echo $?)
done
```

which I am triggering with the workflow

**workflow file**

```
  deploy-to-gcloud:
    needs: [ test-and-build ]
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Download a Build Artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3.0.1
      with:
        name: build
        path: packages/client/
    
    - id: 'auth'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'

    - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'
    
    - name: 'Use gcloud CLI'  
      run: |
          cd packages/client/
          mkdir ../deploy
          sudo mv build ../deploy/
          sudo mv app.yaml ../deploy/ 
          cd ../deploy
          gcloud info
          gcloud app deploy --version=${{ github.sha }}
          gcloud app browse --version=${{ github.sha }}

test-after-deployment:
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [ deploy-to-gcloud ]
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: installing dependencies
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install wget
        wget -S <WEBSITE GOES HERE>
    
    - name: check website
      run: |
          # This the area that is not returning the expected output
          sudo chmod u+x .github/workflows/test.sh
          timeout 300 .github/workflows/test.sh ${{ github.sha }}

test-while-deployment:
      
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: [ test-and-build ]
      
      steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: installing dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install wget
          wget -S <WEBSITE GOES HERE>
      
      - name: check website
        run: |
            sudo chmod u+x .github/workflows/test.sh
            timeout 600 .github/workflows/test.sh ${{ github.sha }}
  
test-after-deployment-2:
      
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: [ deploy-to-gcloud ]
      
      steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: installing dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install wget
          wget -S <WEBSITE GOES HERE>
      
      - name: check website
        run: |
            sudo chmod u+x .github/workflows/test.sh
            timeout 600 .github/workflows/test.sh ${{ github.sha }}
```

I ran three similar jobs [test-while-deployment and test-after-deployment-2 are the jobs created for troubleshooting] the main job is **test-after-deployment**

I tried running it in different ways but it seems to fail and does not have any repeating pattern

I ran it 10 times from my computer and the github codespaces and these are the results that i recorded manually

**these tests were pushing from local pc :**

- Test 1 failed with (1st : wget & 2nd : curl)
- Test 2 passed with (all 4 commands)
- Test 3 passed with (both wget commands)
- Test 4 passed with (both wget commands)
- Test 5 failed with (wget,curl,wget)
- Test 6 passed with (both wget commands)
- Test 7 failed with (1st : wget & 2nd : curl)
- Test 8 passed with (1st : curl & 2nd: wget)
- Test 9 passed with (both curl commands)
- Test 10 passed with (both wget commands)

**these tests are from github codespaces :**

- Test 1 failed with (1st : wget & 2nd : curl)
- Test 2 failed with (wget ,curl,wget)
- Test 3 failed with (both wget commands)
- Test 4 passed with (all 4 commands)
- Test 5 passed with (both curl commands)
- Test 6 passed with (both wget commands)
- Test 7 failed with (1st : wget & 2nd : curl)
- Test 8 failed with (1st : curl & 2nd : wget)
- Test 9 failed with (both curl commands)
- Test 10 failed with (both wget commands)

I expected it to work properly and not fail most of the time

**UPDATE**

It never finds the html content and returns the error when it fails

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$status" != "0" ]; do
    sleep 5
    # curl <WEBSITE GOES HERE>
    wget -S --spider <WEBSITE GOES HERE> 2>&1 | grep HTTP/
    # curl -v --silent <WEBSITE GOES HERE> 2>&1 | grep -Po d7c1bd01d1ccdfe9357b534458c9cc59594796af
    wget <WEBSITE GOES HERE> -q -O - | grep -Po d7c1bd01d1ccdfe9357b534458c9cc59594796af
    status=$(echo $?)
done
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
.
.
.
.
.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Error: Process completed with exit code 124.
```

It returns the html content whenever it succeed

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
.
.
.
.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
d7c1bd01d1ccdfe9357b534458c9cc59594796af
```

Comment: You need to elaborate on the exact failures. What are the error messages or what happens for those cases?

Comment: @DanielStenberg - What is happening here is there is one job that runs `gcloud app deploy` to deploy a new version of the app. There two other jobs that perform a health check. Sometimes, you'll see one job is able to run curl and get the HTML content while the other job gets nothing.  There are no errors, and there's a 200 status code, just no HTML content is returned.  The two jobs were created because there was a suspicion that something might be happening that's network related.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit mistaken.  It seems that one job is seeing the old HTML from the site, while another job is seeing the new content, when running curl or wget.  It's as if the HTML from the server isn't propagating across different Google Data centers or something like that.   The health check is specifically looking for an embedded version number in the meta tags to validate that it is deployed in the CI server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update / Solution**

It seems like the `curl` and `wget` commands were caching in between the client side and the server side somewhere which was the reason why the commands were returning the same repetitive results

I got through this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/curl-without-cache)
then I realized that caching may be the reason for this behavior

I used

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store' -v --silent <WEBSITE GOES HERE> 2>&1 | grep -Po d7c1bd01d1ccdfe9357b534458c9cc59594796af

wget --no-cache <WEBSITE GOES HERE> -q -O - | grep -Po d7c1bd01d1ccdfe9357b534458c9cc59594796af
```

These commands instead of the ones I was using before.

So basically,

You can use `'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store'` with the `curl` command

and `--no-cache` flag with the `wget` command.

Hopefully, this might help you all if you got stuck in something similar to this problem.